# How do I use Pandas to iterate through an xlsx sheet and only read certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have an excel sheet with the fields 'URN' 'GUID', and 'CODE', along with a few other columns. Is there a way I can use the python pandas library to iterate through each row and pull out it's respective values for 'URN' 'GUID', and 'CODE'?

Comment: Would you like to remove these three columns or do you want to iterate over each row in them to find some values?

Comment: The goal is to iterate over each of these rows and print their values. So it should be every row's value of 'URN', 'GUID' and 'CODE'.

Comment: When you create a dataframe, you can do: df = pd.read_excel(filepath, usecols=['URN', 'GUID', 'CODE'])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to read certain columns from Excel using Pandas - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655127/how-to-read-certain-columns-from-excel-using-pandas-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are just willing to read certain columns, from your excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path_of_your_file, usecols=['URN', 'GUID', 'CODE'])
```

Then you can iterate through rows of df